# How would I show, in a Google Sheets cell, the number of issues found in a JIRA search

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google sheet that creates URLs to JIRA with project ID and some parameters to have specific searches available from the "hub" sheet for each project listed. What I'd like to do is have the text in the hyperlink cell display the number of issues in the search from the link.

Now I'd just like to know what's the best way to do this, as I'm not a programmer at all so I'd rather spend time learning something that will end up working instead of just trying things on my own .-.

Could a kind soul maybe let me know what they think the best tool/flow for this would be?

PS: The reason I'm bothering with a sheet and not a JIRA Dashboard is that the order and list of the projects I need to keep track of changes every one or two days :[

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls with example of desired output

Comment: The sheet looks something like this, but with more projects / info. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QtM2tebaakvWthG138Vf2JMsyEA8UrXBq1R84gUB24c/edit?usp=sharing

What I'm looking for right now is a way to have the two cells D3 and E3 in the example to show the number of issues that the search in the hyperlink returns.

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for scraping the generated URL, you will need to use one of the import formulae which fits your need

- `IMPORTHTML`
- `IMPORTXML`
- `IMPORTDATA`
- etc.

then all you is combine it like:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("URL link to search"), IMPORT...())
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a great tool to use, however when I try to apply this to my URL it says it "Failed to fetch URL" .-.

I'm unsure if the cause could be that JIRA requires login to access the search, or something among those lines?

Comment: you cant scrape stuff behind login nor if its controlled by JavaScript - those are two main Google Sheets limitations